# Why does my BitBake autotools recipe fail during do_configure?

Tags: autotools, configure, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am attempting to create a fairly simple BitBake recipe that uses autotools, which you can see here:

```
SUMMARY = "an example autotools recipe"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

inherit autotools 
SRC_URI = "file://${TOPDIR}/piu/geo_utilities"
S = "${TOPDIR}/piu/geo_utilities"
```

After starting a BitBake build with this recipe's default package included,   `do_configure` fails with the following:

```
configure: exit 0
WARNING: /home/presslertj/repos/new-bb-layers/poky-jethro-build/build/tmp/work/x86-poky-linux/geo-utilities/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_configure.48030:1 exit 1 from
  exit 1
```

which seems contradictory.  [Here's](http://pastebin.com/EUG0iNQN) the full log. What would cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: From the log it seems to indicate the configure has already been run; have you done it? Could you also check the `${WORKDIR}/build/` directory, before and after running the configure step? (As you're running jethro, the build should be out-of-tree). How dous the filelisting in geo_utilities look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first"

This basically means you've changed ${B}, but if you do that with autotools you'll generally need to wipe away the existing build first.  At a guess, you've gone from autotools-brokensep to autotools, or you were running configure in the unpacked tree manually.

A quick 'bitbake -c clean geo-utilities' will delete the unpacked source tree, then bitbaking again should work fine.

Comment: I was facing this _source dir already configured_ error in one of my autotools package. Inheriting autotools-brokensep instead of autotools fixed it for me.