# Configure fails on `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB, glib-2.0 >= 2.12.3)'

Tags: configure, glib, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am attempting to create a fairly simple BitBake recipe that uses autotools, which you can see here:

```
SUMMARY = "an example autotools recipe"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
inherit autotools 
SRC_URI = "file://${TOPDIR}/piu/geo_utilities"
S = "${TOPDIR}/piu/geo_utilities"
```

After starting a BitBake build with this recipe's default package included,   `do_configure` fails with the following:

```
configure: line 12851: syntax error near unexpected token `GLIB,'          
configure: line 12851: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB, glib-2.0 >= 2.12.3)'
```

When I run `ldd --version`, I get this: `ldd (GNU libc) 2.17`.

I've found several sites like [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/4store-support/VusYwkhk6eo) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/issues/48) which suggest that the problem can be solved by updating pkg-config. I'm running Red Hat, so I've run `sudo yum install pkgconfig` which returns that `pkgconfig-0.27.1-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.

*(this question followed after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753906/why-does-my-bitbake-autotools-recipe-fail-during-do-configure) was solved by the answerer)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper fix is to inherit pkgconfig.  Specifically you need pkgconfig-native built.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this error was due to the `do_configure` step of my custom recipe being ran before the glib for my target machine was generated. I was able to resolve this error by adding this line to the recipe:

```
DEPENDS += " glib-2.0 pkgconfig "
```

Comment: Close but not quite, you need *native* pkg-config not pkg-config for the target.  However building those will cause pkgconfig-native to be built, which is why it appeared to work.

Comment: @RossBurton, why is it that you need pkgconfig-native? I am trying to understand why it matters if the pkgconfig that runs is built for running on the host. Also I actually had trouble with glib-2.0 and one thing I tried was doing an `inherit pkgconfig` which basically is equivalent to `DEPENDS += pkgconfig-native`

Comment: You need pkgconfig-native to get the pkgconfig binaries that work on the build host, as you can't run the pkgconfig binaries that are built for the target.